# How to avoid repeating labels?

Tags: pine-script

```
plotshape(ema50>ema200:na, title = "50x200", location = location.belowbar,text= "50x200", textcolor=color.white,style = shape.labelup, color =color.green, size = size.small)
```

It keeps showing the label as long as 50>200 , but I only want the label once. I do not want to use crossover or crossunder.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below script is a representation for your requirements..

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)
ema50 = ema(close,50)
ema200 = ema(close,200)
Cond1 = ema50>ema200    
plotshape(Cond1 and Cond1!=Cond1[1], title = "50x200", location = location.belowbar,text= "50x200", textcolor=color.white,style = shape.labelup, color =color.green, size = size.small)
plot(ema50, title = "EMA 50")
plot(ema200, color = color.new(color.red,10), title = "EMA 200")
```

Comment: Its prefect. Thanks a lot @MVP_Script